Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AbpEditions'.' Error running an ASP.NET Zero project on Localhost
I am trying to run an already developed project in Visual studio 2022.
Once I run any view such as Login or Register.cshtml it gives me the following error,
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:  'Invalid object name 'AbpEditions'.'
I need to run on the localhost db.
Currently the error is under this function and line
private void CreateEditions()
{
    var defaultEdition = _context.Editions.IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == EditionManager.DefaultEditionName);
    if (defaultEdition == null)
    {
        defaultEdition = new SubscribableEdition { Name = EditionManager.DefaultEditionName, DisplayName = EditionManager.DefaultEditionName };
        _context.Editions.Add(defaultEdition);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        /* Add desired features to the standard edition, if wanted... */
    }

The error is on the particular line as mentioned below,
 var defaultEdition = _context.Editions.IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == EditionManager.DefaultEditionName);

I can see the appsettings.json as mentioned below, Please help me to run this project on localhost as in the connection string it's mentioned.  Thank you
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost; Database=PortalDb; Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  },
  "AbpZeroLicenseCode": "00q8DvKdTtXIYHswRmkLCtjA==38010694451e3acd4afc2ff8ad2949a3",
  "Abp": {
    "RedisCache": {
      "ConnectionString": "localhost",
      "DatabaseId": -1
    }
  },
  "App": {
    "WebSiteRootAddress": "https://localhost:44302/",
    "RedirectAllowedExternalWebSites": "https://localhost:44303/",
    "SwaggerEndPoint": "/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
    "AuditLog": {
      "AutoDeleteExpiredLogs": {
        "IsEnabled": false,
        "ExcelBackup": {
          "IsEnabled": false,
          "FilePath": "App_Data/AuditLogsBackups/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "AllowSocialLoginSettingsPerTenant": false,
    "Facebook": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "AppId": "",
      "AppSecret": ""
    },
    "Google": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "ClientId": "",
      "ClientSecret": "",
      "UserInfoEndpoint": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo"
    },
    "Twitter": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "ConsumerKey": "",
      "ConsumerSecret": ""
    },
    "Microsoft": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "ConsumerKey": "",
      "ConsumerSecret": ""
    },
    "WsFederation": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "MetaDataAddress": "",
      "Wtrealm": ""
    },
    "JwtBearer": {
      "IsEnabled": "true",
      "SecurityKey": "FA84F74701E64D2483583119E8D51960",
      "Issuer": "Portal",
      "Audience": "Portal"
    },
    "OpenId": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "Authority": "",
      "ClientId": "",
      "ClientSecret": "",
      "ValidateIssuer": "false",
      "ResponseType": "code",
      "ClaimsMapping": [
        {
          "claim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
          "key": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Configuration": {
    "AzureKeyVault": {
      "IsEnabled": "false",
      "KeyVaultName": "",
      "TenantId": "",
      "ClientId": "",
      "ClientSecret": ""
    }
  },
  "Twilio": {
    "AccountSid": "",
    "AuthToken": "",
    "SenderNumber": ""
  },
  "Recaptcha": {
    "SiteKey": "6LeEZ-kUAAAAAGdgiM9BoWiRKBZOeULch73OlyZP",
    "SecretKey": "6LeEZ-kUAAAAADBrLM1zkIy0mF_4rbBp3toA6zIJ"
  },
  "OpenIddict": {
    "IsEnabled": "false",
    "Applications": [
      {
        "ClientId": "client",
        "ClientSecret": "def2edf7-5d42-4edc-a84a-30136c340e13",
        "DisplayName": "Portal_App",
        "ConsentType": "Explicit",
        "RedirectUris": [
          "https://oauthdebugger.com/debug"
        ],
        "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [],
        "Scopes": [
          "default-api",
          "profile"
        ],
        "Permissions": [
          "ept:token",
          "ept:authorization",
          "gt:password",
          "gt:client_credentials",
          "gt:authorization_code",
          "rst:code",
          "rst:code id_token"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Payment": {
    "PayPal": {
      "IsActive": "true",
      "Environment": "sandbox",
      "ClientId": "",
      "ClientSecret": "",
      "DemoUsername": "",
      "DemoPassword": "",
      "DisabledFundings": []
    },
    "Stripe": {
      "IsActive": "true",
      "BaseUrl": "https://api.stripe.com/v1",
      "SecretKey": "sk_test_51MYU0CIpx5mPWWPGrSpj3dFMzgURwiCCDo2pJk393K3ZqUayRmE539p4JbL71tphG67J4EfUpimSZNlzdTUDfWig00V5GNkh33",
      "PublishableKey": "pk_test_51MYU0CIpx5mPWWPGHuVYEqAmMsnqv0BU5SQSa4sCTeNSHEV1ntEzG4nNAAxsviwwYBBxRcBPCkOgGoh6P7EIXjLy005qOE2nCa",
      "WebhookSecret": "whsec_b79b5fb8088640f4e6b9ccaa54d90168fb256280aa8503100449dc20a16240e2",
      "PaymentMethodTypes": [
        "card"
      ]
    }
  },
  "HealthChecks": {
    "HealthChecksEnabled": true,
    "HealthChecksUI": {
      "HealthChecksUIEnabled": true,
      "HealthChecks": [
        {
          "Name": "Portal.Web.MVC",
          "Uri": "https://localhost:44302/health"
        }
      ],
      "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 10,
      "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
    }
  },
  "KestrelServer": {
    "IsEnabled": false
  },
  "LocaleMappings": {
    "Moment": [
      {
        "from": "zh-Hans",
        "to": "zh-cn"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Swagger": {
    "ShowSummaries": false
  }
}

Please find the program.cs down below,
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Abp.Application.Services.Dto;
using Abp.Json;
using IdentityModel.Client;
using Abp.Web.Models;
using Portal.Authorization.Users.Dto;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Portal.ConsoleApiClient
{
    /* 
     * This is a sample code to create an IdentityServer4 client and use ResourceOwnerPassword flow to call an API. 
     * Enable IdentityServer from appsettings.json of Web.Host/Web.Mvc project first.
     */

    class Program
    {
        private const string ServerUrlBase = "https://localhost:44301/";

        // If you have changed "Configuration.MultiTenancy.TenantIdResolveKey" in your web app, use the same value here. 
        private const string TenantIdResolveKey = "Abp.TenantId";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunDemoAsync().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task RunDemoAsync()
        {
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenViaOwnerPasswordAsync();
            await GetUsersListAsync(accessToken);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenViaOwnerPasswordAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(ServerUrlBase);
            if (disco.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception(disco.Error);
            }

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Abp.TenantId", "1");  //Set TenantId
            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecret = "def2edf7-5d42-4edc-a84a-30136c340e13",

                Scope = "default-api",

                UserName = "admin",
                Password = "123qwe"
            });

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: ");
                Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);

            return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        }

        private static async Task GetUsersListAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

                var response = await client.PostAsync($"{ServerUrlBase}api/services/app/user/getUsers", new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                    return;
                }

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var ajaxResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AjaxResponse<PagedResultDto<UserListDto>>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                });

                if (!ajaxResponse.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ajaxResponse.Error?.Message ?? "Remote service throws exception!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Total user count: " + ajaxResponse.Result.TotalCount);
                Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (var user in ajaxResponse.Result.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"### UserId: {user.Id}, UserName: {user.UserName}");
                    Console.WriteLine(user.ToJsonString(indented: true));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Please find the PortalDbContext.cs under EntityFramework Core folder.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using Abp.OpenIddict.Applications;
using Abp.OpenIddict.Authorizations;
using Abp.OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Abp.OpenIddict.Scopes;
using Abp.OpenIddict.Tokens;
using Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portal.Authorization.Delegation;
using Portal.Authorization.Roles;
using Portal.Authorization.Users;
using Portal.Chat;
using Portal.Editions;
using Portal.ExtraProperties;
using Portal.Friendships;
using Portal.MultiTenancy;
using Portal.MultiTenancy.Accounting;
using Portal.MultiTenancy.Payments;
using Portal.Storage;

namespace Portal.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class PortalDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, PortalDbContext>, IOpenIddictDbContext
    {
        /* Define an IDbSet for each entity of the application */

        public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictApplication> Applications { get; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictAuthorization> Authorizations { get; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictScope> Scopes { get; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictToken> Tokens { get; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<BinaryObject> BinaryObjects { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<SubscribableEdition> SubscribableEditions { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<SubscriptionPayment> SubscriptionPayments { get; set; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<SubscriptionPaymentProduct> SubscriptionPaymentProducts { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<UserDelegation> UserDelegations { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<RecentPassword> RecentPasswords { get; set; }

        public PortalDbContext(DbContextOptions<PortalDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BinaryObject>(b => { b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId }); });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPayment>(x =>
            {
                x.Property(u => u.ExtraProperties)
                    .HasConversion(
                        d => JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, new JsonSerializerOptions()
                        {
                            WriteIndented = false
                        }),
                        s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExtraPropertyDictionary>(s, new JsonSerializerOptions()
                        {
                            WriteIndented = false
                        })
                    );
            });
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPaymentProduct>(x =>
            {
                x.Property(u => u.ExtraProperties)
                    .HasConversion(
                        d => JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, new JsonSerializerOptions()
                        {
                            WriteIndented = false
                        }),
                        s => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExtraPropertyDictionary>(s, new JsonSerializerOptions()
                        {
                            WriteIndented = false
                        })
                    );
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.FriendUserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.UserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.FriendUserId });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.SubscriptionEndDateUtc });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.CreationTime });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPayment>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Status, e.CreationTime });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { PaymentId = e.ExternalPaymentId, e.Gateway });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDelegation>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.SourceUserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.TargetUserId });
            });
            
            modelBuilder.ConfigureOpenIddict();
        }
    }
}


The error says you're trying to use a non-existent table. Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database? Have you created the table AbpEditions ?

I can see a lot of tables under master,model,msdb or tempdb.  Not sure where to add the table on the localhost. @PanagiotisKanavos

Does the PortalDb database in use exist locally? If so, in the PortalDb database, check whether the AbpEditions table exists? And are there related migration files in the Migrations folder?

@YuningDuan I'll update you shortly with a code. thanks

@YuningDuan Till now I couldn't see any table but I am wondering if I create a PortalDb on a localhost what would be the fields name in it ? And Is there any need to create an AbpEdition table ?
